# flask - jinja template forloop increasing loop index

Tags: python, templates, for-loop, flask, jinja2

I'm working on a flask project. In Jinja template there is a problem for me in the for loop. I want to print the first index of the first index of a dictionary.
The output of `newlist` is:

```
{1: [{'uid': 407, 'color': red},
{'uid': 407, 'color': black},
{'uid': 407, 'color': white}], 2:
[{'uid': 372, 'color': pink},
{'uid': 372, 'color': blue},
{'uid': 372, 'color': orange}], 3:
[{'uid': 28, 'color': green}]}
```

I want to get the output like this:

```
{'uid': 407, 'color': red}
{'uid': 407, 'color': black}
{'uid': 407, 'color': white}

{'uid': 372, 'color': pink}
{'uid': 372, 'color': blue}
{'uid': 372, 'color': orange}

{'uid': 28, 'color': green}
```

How I can edit this for loop to reach that output? Here I have set both indexes manual `( newlist.1.1 )`, how I can increase index number correctly?

```
{% for each in newlist %}
    {{ newlist.1.1 }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just treat it the way you would treat a dictionary outside the template, that's the point of Jinja templates:

```
>>> newlist  = {1: [{'uid': 407, 'color': 'red'}, {'uid': 407, 'color': 'black'}, {'uid': 407, 'color': 'white'}], 2: [{'uid': 372, 'color': 'pink'}, {'uid': 372, 'color': 'blue'}, {'uid': 372, 'color': 'orange'}], 3: [{'uid': 28, 'color': 'green'}]}
>>> 
>>> for k in newlist :
        for d in newlist[k]:
            print(d)


{'uid': 407, 'color': 'red'}
{'uid': 407, 'color': 'black'}
{'uid': 407, 'color': 'white'}
{'uid': 372, 'color': 'pink'}
{'uid': 372, 'color': 'blue'}
{'uid': 372, 'color': 'orange'}
{'uid': 28, 'color': 'green'}
```

So, in your template:

```
{% for k in newlist %}
    {% for d in newlist[k] %}
        {{ d }}<\br>
    {% endfor %}
    <\br>
{% endfor %}
```